# HP 2540 AIO printer in Ubuntu 17.04 - how to install?

Tags: printing, hp

I've been a happy Ubuntu user for quite some years now and I have never had any problems in install HP printers.
However, my `HP 2540 AIO` fails to install, even though it worked flawlessly on 16.x

I've install `hplip` and `hplib-data`.  When I run `hp-setup` it simply fails to find anything.

If I try to install the printer using the built-in Printers app in Settings, it suggests that the printer "lives" on serial port #5... I can add this as a printer port, assign the correct printer driver and such (I guess it's wireless printing) - but nothing happens when I press the <kbd>Print a test page</kbd> button ...

Nothing has been written to the log files.

---

I'm pretty much stuck here - any pointers are welcome.  If nothing else, I'll downgrade to the 16.x :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Download HPLIP 3.17.4

https://sourceforge.net/projects/hplip/files/hplip/3.17.4/hplip-3.17.4.run/download?use_mirror=ufpr

Run the Automatic Installer

Open a terminal,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Run it:

```
cd Desktop ---- (assume that the hplip-3.17.4.run file was downloaded to your Desktop directory)
sh hplip-3.17.4.run
```

Select the install mode: Automatic (enter an 'a')

Verify your Linux Distribution

Enter Your Sudo User Password

Read the Installation Notes. Please follow any directions given.

'./configure' and 'make' will run

'make install' is run

Use 'hp-setup' to configure your printer

Select How Your Printer will be Connected to Your Computer

Select the Printer to be Configured

Select the PPD file (or driver) to be Used for Your Printer, usually you will want to select the recommended PPD file.

Confirm the Printer Settings and Finish the Configuration Process, click "AddPrinter"

Comment: Thanks - it worked.   I hope Canonical will update the drivers ... :-)

Comment: this is all very strange; that is a 4yr old printer; and HP says it needs only 3.13.4 for hplip; http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/models/deskjet_aio/deskjet_2540_series.html and 16.04 Ubuntu is running 3.16.3 so it should be fine with hplip: so you should really have just needed to run the hplip on your machine to configure it ; if one runs "sudo hp-check" http://hplipopensource.com/node/332 it should awaken hplip if it is dozing when a new HP is connected

Comment: Tried hplip 3.16.3 under Ubuntu 16.04. Printer found Ok but did nothing when I tried to print test page. Printer Properties says that Printer State is "Processing - Processing page 1" but Document Print Status is "Processing - Not connected?". After a time, a window pops up from hplip saying that device is busy. lsusb shows "Bus 002 Device 010: ID 03f0:c211 Hewlett-Packard". Same problem with installing hplip 3.13.4 (and 3.17.9) using instructions in answer.

Comment: I've run "sudo hp-check": it gave error & warning about missing python3-dev & python3-notify2. So I installed them using Synaptic (it also brought in some other dependent packages). However, it gave "warning: Printer is not HPLIP installed. Printers must use the hp: or hpfax: CUPS backend for HP-Devices". Any ideas?

Comment: I've reported this as a bug at https://sourceforge.net/projects/hplip/files/hplip/3.17.4/hplip-3.17.4.run/download?use_mirror=ufpr